# Need assistance with an Owl Carousel error. How can I resolve it? Seeking guidance for troubleshooting and fixing the issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm encountering an issue while trying to incorporate Owl Carousel using jQuery in Adobe Dreamweaver, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve it. The error message I'm receiving suggests that something might be amiss. Could you please guide me in troubleshooting and fixing this issue?

I recently integrated Owl Carousel with jQuery into my web project using Adobe Dreamweaver. However, I've run into a problem, and I'm not entirely sure what's causing it. The error message I'm encountering is:

```
 <div class="slider-area">
        <div class="slider-active owl-carousel">
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-active').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        navText:['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        nav:true,
        responsive:[
        0:{
        items:1
        },
        600:{
        items:1
        }
        1000:{
        items:1
        }
    })
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue. If there's additional information or code snippets required, please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly? We cant really help without that. That said, 10 to 1 you are not properly including the needed files and getting something like "owlCarousel is not a function"

Comment: Actually, the value you have for the key `responsive` is syntactically wrong. Not sure what you mean to do there but you have an opening `[` that you never close and inside it, you are using keys so maybe you meant for that to be `{`?

Comment: please let us know the error. Also did you added jQuery library and owl-carousel files?

Comment: "Here, Jquery Error." – What is the error?

Comment: "Where is error in Jquery?" – The error message tells you where the error is.

Comment: "Here, Jquery Error." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 3):

Your responsive prop is an array. In the docs it is an object:

```js
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
```